# Can I upload multiple data to different webpages at the same time?

Tags: powershell

We work at a boat selling company that apart from selling boats from our website, we sell them through other boat selling webpages (i.e. bottrader.com, onlyinboards.com...). But we waste a lot of time uploading the boat pictures and details to one webpage at a time. So, is there any way to upload them to all of the websites at the same time using PowerShell? If yes, could you please guide me a little bit on how to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Powershell can send data to the web in numerous ways like ```Invoke-RestMethod``` of using FTP - Can you please elaborate more on how you currently uploads the files or what you have tried so far?

Comment: We have to log into an account, and then click 'create' button and fill text boxes and upload pictures. I have just tried to do the log in to the the account